How to change the execution options of a session and use the fetchmany option
I'm trying to adapt the following code (from this answer:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select

conn = create_engine("DB URL...").connect()
q = select([huge_table])

proxy = conn.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(q)

while 'batch not empty':  # equivalent of 'while True', but clearer
    batch = proxy.fetchmany(100000)  # 100,000 rows at a time

    if not batch:
        break

    for row in batch:
        # Do your stuff here...

proxy.close()


to use Session instead of the connection directly. I basically create sessions like this:
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

where
engine = create_engine(get_db_url(), **SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS)
create_database(engine.url)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


Any idea how to use the execution options and fetchmany equivalent but with sessions?
This works:
db.execute(select(EventConfigurationDB)).fetchmany(100)

But this does not:
db.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(select(EventConfigurationDB)).fetchmany(100)


You can use yield_per.
Here is a complete example.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Something(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'something'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///temp.db', echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add_all(Something() for _ in range(100))
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    statement = select(Something).execution_options(yield_per=10)
    result = session.execute(statement)
    while 'batch not empty':
        batch = result.fetchmany(10)
        if not batch:
            break
        print(len(batch))

To answer the direct question. You can do session.execute(select(Something).execution_options(stream_results=True)).fetchmany(100).
